# window.print() position DIV center of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Anyone knows how to align the printable content in the middle of the page of 8.5x11 sheet of paper? Heres my `div`

```
<div id = "printable">
<table>
//my table content
</table>
</div>
```

i tried using this css

```
@media print {
#printable{
     position:absolute;
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
     z-index:15;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-150px 0 0 -150px;
     }
}
```

but clicking my print button will do this jquery stuff

```
var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
var printcontent = document.getElementById('printable').innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;       
location.reload();
```

using this jquery will replace the whole page content in the background
after printing to restore the previous content thats why centering the div doesnt work TYIA for helping me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find below an example of centering the contents only on print

```js
var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
var printcontent = document.getElementById('printable').innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
//location.reload();
```

```css
@media print {
#printable{
     display:flex;
     justify-content:center;
     align-items:center;
     height:100%;
     }
    html, body{
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id = "printable">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```